# NSDate get the values one day before today

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I try to get date today using this code:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Today: %@", today);
```

the result is:

> January 30, 2013 +00:00:00

But the current date is

> January 29, 2013 +00:00:00

Any idea, to how solve this case?

Comment: When you use the `%@` format specifier to display an `NSDate` as a string, the date is always shown in Zulu time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
NSDate* today = [NSDate date];
```

Also, remember that if you look at "today" you will see the date in GMT, not your local time.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here are two things to check out:

1. Make sure the clock of the device is set correctly.
2. Make sure you are using the correct time zone.

Ingo.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSLog(@"Today: %@",[today  descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
```

`NSDate` returns date in `GMT`.Above will convert date in your `currentLocale`.

Comment: Locale is separate from time zone.

Comment: The result is Today: 30 january  2013 19:00:00 Hour Colombia but the current date is 29 January 2013 23:14:00 Hour Colombia